# How to rewrite nginx non-existing file under condition?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

For a mature website I only need to generate a thumbnail once, using timthumb, which places the thumbnail in /thumbs/.

```
try_files $uri ^thumbs/(.*)$ /thumb.php?w=290&q=90&src=../full/%1 last;
```

How could I fix this code?

Working apache code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/thumbs/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /thumb.php?h=90&q=90&src=../full/%1 [NS,L]
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change `%1` to `$1` in the `try_files` directive.

Comment: Hm, I now have this. But het just says the configuration file test failed. http://pastebin.com/P1Yk7zP4

Comment: Right, the `try_files` directive can't actually do rewrites. I think you'd have to use `try_files $uri /thumb.php?src=$uri;`, and either modify thumb.php to accept an entire URL as the source, or add a `rewrite` directive under a `location` block for `/thumb.php`.